# self need in call to parent class by name when using multi inheritance

Tags: python, class, self

Edit: Thanks for the replies. This is a practice exercise from a website that I'm using to learn, I haven't designed it. I want to confirm that the Wolf.action(self) is an static call and ask why would you make Wolf inherit from Animal if you can only use Dog Class' methods with super() due to MRO (in Diamond scheme). Is there any point on making a subclass inherit from several independent classes since you can only use super() with the first one listed in the definition? Does it have anything to do with imports?

So, in this code:

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
 
class Dog(Animal):
  def action(self):
    print("{} wags tail. Awwww".format(self.name))
 
class Wolf(Animal):
  def action(self):
    print("{} bites. OUCH!".format(self.name))
 
class Hybrid(Dog, Wolf):
  def action(self):
    super().action()
    Wolf.action(self)
 
my_pet = Hybrid("Fluffy")
my_pet.action() # Fluffy wags tail. Awwww
                # Fluffy bites. OUCH!
```

Why do I have to provide `self` in `Wolf.action(self)` but not in `super().action()`?
Why can't I just do `Wolf.action()`?

I'm guessing this is just an static call, and thus that's why I need to pass an explicit parameter. But then, what is the point of multi inheritance in this context? Wouldn't it be the same if `Hybrid` doesn't inherit from `Wolf`?

I've read some other threads but the majority of them talk about MRO and that is not the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, this isn't the way to implement this really, IMO. Super should either be used in a case of simple inheritance, or cooperative multiple inheritance *with a single call to super* (see chepner's answer). If you don't want that, I think it is better  (more clear) to explicitly call both.

Comment: "But then, what is the point of multi inheritance in this context? " **you tell us**. This is *your code*.

Comment: "What I've been told is that Python needs this explicit self to assure that Wolf.action(self) grabs the instance of the Hybrid class, and not the parent one" No, that is just incorrect. **there is only one instance anyway** and it is an instance of `Hybrid`. There is no instance of any other of the classes you defined existing in your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right about the supposed instance of the parent class. I made that up, my bad. Editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wolf.action` is the actual function, not a bound method that implicitly includes `self` when you try to call it.

However, if you use `super` properly, you don't need an explicit call to `Wolf.action`.

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def action(self):
      pass
 
class Dog(Animal):
  def action(self):
    super().action()
    print("{} wags tail. Awwww".format(self.name))
 
class Wolf(Animal):
  def action(self):
    super().action()
    print("{} bites. OUCH!".format(self.name))
 
class Hybrid(Wolf, Dog):
  pass

my_pet = Hybrid("Fluffy")
my_pet.action() # Fluffy wags tail. Awwww
            # Fluffy bites. OUCH!
```

Comment: What if any is the impact of the order of Dog and Wolf in the class definition of Hybrid? I see you changed the order from OP's, and switching them back changes the order of the printed output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, chepner. I don't understand why you define action() in Animal, and if I'm not wrong, you changed the order in Hybrid definition so Wolf is the first listed for it to be the one invoked when making the call (you altered the MRO).

So now in my_pet.action(), its the Wolf.action() method what is going to be picked, but not the other one. Just that one. Am i wrong?

Comment: Both get called. When you try to call `Hybrid.action`, `Wolf.action` is chosen. But that call involves a call to `super().action` itself, and the next class after `Wolf` is `Dog`, so `Dog.action` gets called. *That* method also calls `super().action`, which means `Animal.action` gets called next. `Animal.action`, finally, does nothing, and more importantly does not use `super().action` itself, so that you don't incorrectly try to call `object.action` (which is not defined).

Comment: That is actually insane. I understand from what you say that it actually behaves like multi level inheritance: like if Wolf inherited from Dog and Dog from Animal, and each subsequent class adds something extra. I understand that when Wolf.action is called, apart from calling super, prints its own statement, and so does Dog. So, in the end, you get both prints from both Animal subclasses and then the empty Animal.action.

Is then Dog here considered super() of Wolf just because of MRO? Even if Wolf doesnt actually inherit from Dog?

Comment: Kind of. The MRO of `self` can contain classes from unrelated hierarchies. Something called the C3 linearization algorithm has the job of taking the entire *tree* of 'superclasses' and putting the classes in a linear order that makes sense (for some useful definition of "sense"), which means a class is not always *immediately* followed by its parent class in the MRO.

Comment: (Though one property of the C3 linearization is that a class always *precedes* all of its immediate parents in the MRO. The other defining property is that the order of parent classes as listed in a `class` definition is always preserved.)

Comment: I think I got it. I´ll have to try all these out. Thank you very much for your time, honestly, so helpful.